# JQuery Accordion Styling: Blue Box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I integrated an accordion into my application, but when I click on the header, the entire header is outlined in blue.  How do I get rid of this?  (In my javascript, I do have something to set the header font color to blue, but I don't think this should affect the border; when I remove the javascript function, it doesn't remove the border).

[image]

```
       <div class="userComments">
        <div class="accordion">
          <h5> Comments (<%=step.comment_threads.count%>)</h5>
          <div class="comment">  
            <% if user_signed_in?%>
            <div class="userIcon">
              <% if current_user.avatar_url != nil %>
                <%= image_tag(current_user.avatar_url(:thumb), :class=>"commentAvatar img-polaroid")%>
              <% else %>
                 <%= image_tag("default_avatar.png", :class=>"commentAvatar img-polaroid") %>
              <% end %>
            </div class="addComment">
               <%= semantic_form_for([@project, step, step.comment_threads.build]) do |f| %>
                <div class="field">
                  <%= f.text_area :body %>
                </div>
            <div class="submit">
              <%= f.submit :comment, :class=> "btn btn-small btn-primary commentSubmit" %>
            </div>
            <% end %>
            <% else %>
            <p> Please <%= link_to "sign in", user_session_path, {:style=> "font-weight:bold;"} %> to leave comments </p>
            <% end %>

             <div class="clear"></div>
          <div class="stepComments">
            <% if step.comment_threads.count >0 %>
              <% step.comment_threads.each do |stepComment| %>
                <% if stepComment.body.length>0 %>
                  <%= render :partial => 'comments', :locals => {:comment=> stepComment, :step=>step} %>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
          </div>
        </div>



<script type="text/javascript">
      (function($) { 

        $('.accordion').accordion({
          collapsible: true, 
          heightStyle: "content",
          active: false,
          icons:{
            header: "icon-chevron-down",
            activeHeader: "icon-chevron-up"
          }
        });

        $('.accordion h5').hover(function(){
          $(this).css("color", "#0769AD");
        },
        function(){
          $(this).css("color", "#000");
        }); 

      })(jQuery);


      </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up being very simple, just didn't know the attribute name (outline):

in my css:

```
.userComments h5{
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size: small;
    outline: none;
}
```